# vertical scroll bar on overlay

Tags: html, css

I have an overlay that I created with a width of 700px and height of 500px.
The contents of it will be quite long though and so the user will have to be able to scroll up/down within the overlay.

Could I get a suggestion on how to set this up taking into consideration the fact that scroll bars vary in width in each browser?

For example if I add 15px of padding-right to the overlay wrapper, it displays great in Firefox.
The contents will fit perfectly within the div and a horizontal bar will not appear.

However in another browser, the vertical scroll bar may be 20px wide, this would cause the contents to be forced to scroll horizontally, or, if I disable overflow-x, they would be cut off by 5px on the right.

How can I get it so that, no matter the browser, when the vertical scroll bar appears, the width of the overlay wrapper adjusts so that its contents can be displayed perfectly with no horizontal scroll bar?

Comment: put `height=100%;` for the overlay

Comment: excuse me, I think i wasn't clear. I can't use height: 100% because that causes the entire page to then scroll, I want to simply scroll within the overlay itself. I will update my question above to be more clear.

Comment: You mean that the overlay should take a dynamic height depend upon the content and browser?

Comment: No the width/height of the wrapper are static, 700px by 500px. But the contents within the overlay is set to 700px by 900px so there will be a scroll bar on the right of the overlay. If I set the wrapper to 715px and the contents to 700px, everything displays fine. But what if in another browser the scroll bar is actually <15px, it will break the layout. How can I adjust for this?

Comment: its the default behavior of html. first, the overlay > content. if content > overlay, the scrollbar should appear. you have to maintain this for cross browser compatibly

Comment: the scroll bar are comes for userfriendly and the width of the scrollbar are by default. you may use padding:10px for the popup so it will display good in all browsers.

Comment: @krish If this is an answer, shouldn't you you post it? =p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Overflow property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) sounds like what you need: `overflow:scroll;`? But I guess I'm not sure what your concern of the different width of scrollbars is. How is it setup that this is variable?

Or a different look at your problem, put the div with your overlay wrapper inside another div and have the new div have the scroll property, thus making it so the first directly has nothing to do with scroll bars. Ex: [[link](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyomu/gxRhW/)]

**EDIT:** Looking at example you provided, do you want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyomu/gxRhW/6/)? Trick is like I said above putting div around everything, but instead not giving it a width and having it `display:inline-block;` ([display](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)) so it fits the child (but the scroll wheel stays outside of the child).

**EDIT 2:** Note if you need it to center on screen, you must have another parent div surrounding the inline-block, and have the inline-block `text-align:center;`. ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyomu/gxRhW/7/))

Comment: Ok I am thinking a link might help here so I am adding a link to original post.

Comment: I tried wrapping an "inner" div and setting the width on that inner, but the scroll bar is still chopping off inner even though it should not be...

Comment: Thanks for the help Kyomu, It seems to be a problem specific to the plugin I am using, I am going to just adjust for it with padding and accept that it may chop a few pixels on certain browsers.

Comment: Alright, so my edited solution didn't work with the plugin, or the plugin is just not working as expected? Just curious, as thought that would have worked =p

Answer (score 0):

use max-width and jquery scrollbar plugin jscrollpane.

You can define the scrollbar width and styles for each browser, if the need it.

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/